# How to set default values for named function parameters simulated via object literals in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object-literal, named-parameters, default-parameters

I'd like to use named parameters (simulated via object literals) in my JavaScript functions for ease of readability. The code I've written works fine when I explicitly pass my parameters, but I'm having trouble trying to set a default value, so that my function can be called not only via as myFunction({someBoolean:true}) OR as myFunction() which would imply a default of someBoolean:false.

```
myFunction: function({myArgs}){
    myArgs.someBoolean = myArgs.someBoolean || false;
    if (myArgs.someBoolean) {
        [do stuff]
    }
    [do other stuff]
},
```

This works fine when I call myFunction({someBoolean:true}), but when I call myFunction(), I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'someBoolean' of undefined."

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the previous answer wouldn't work if you wanted multiple default arguments and some were provided:

Doing `myFunction({otherArg: 'hello'})` wouldn't necessarily set `myArgs.someBoolean` to false.

Rather you should change it the below change:

```
myFunction: function(myArgs){ // Switch to regular argument vs {myArgs}
    myArgs = myArgs || {}; // Make sure it provided

    myArgs.someBoolean = myArgs.someBoolean || false;
    myArgs.otherArg = myArgs.otherArg || 'defaultValue'
    if (myArgs.someBoolean) {
        [do stuff]
    }
    [do other stuff]
},
```

Then this could be called with: `something.myFunction({someBoolean: true, otherArg: '...'})`

Answer (score 4):

```
function x({myArgs}){}
```

is used for object destructuring, such that you can use `myArgs` as a variable inside the function when an object with the `myArgs` property is being passed. For example:

```
function x({myArgs}){
  console.log(myArgs);
}
x({myArgs: 5}); // logs 5
```

However, you’re accessing the boolean like an object property of `myArgs` (`myArgs.someBoolean`). Then you should use this instead:

```
function x(myArgs = {someBoolean: false}){
  console.log(myArgs.someBoolean);
}
x({someBoolean: true}); // logs true
x(); // logs false
```

This now matches your case. If you want to use `someBoolean` directly, use this:

```
function x({someBoolean} = {someBoolean: false}){
  console.log(someBoolean);
}
x({someBoolean: true}); // logs true
x(); // logs false
```

Another option is

```
function x({someBoolean = false, someOtherBoolean = true} = {}){
  console.log(someBoolean);
}
x({someBoolean: true}); // logs true
x(); // logs false
```

[Reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#ES6_version).

Answer (score 3):

The proper way would be

```js
function f({someBoolean = false} = {}){
  console.log(someBoolean)
}
f(); // false
f({}); // false
f({someBoolean: true}); // true
```

That is,

- If no parameter is passed, fallback to `{}`.
- Destruct the parameter or the fallback, extracting the `someBoolean` property as a variable. If there is no such property, fallback to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

```
myFunction: function({someBoolean = false}){
    if (someBoolean) {
        [do stuff]
    }
    [do other stuff]
},
```